# Defining non-Int constants in Haskell within an ADT

Tags: haskell, constants, algebraic-data-types

I'm learning Haskell and as part of the process I'm trying to build a toy program, modelling pizza sizes as an Algebraic Data Type.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
    data Size = Small | Medium | Large | ExtraLarge
        deriving Show
```

Which is OK in the sense that this models the fact that the valid sizes are finite and defined, but it does not model the notion of how big *numerically* those sizes are.

One solution could be, as [suggested in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14799264/222529), to derive from `Enum` and write `fromEnum` and `toEnum`. Then again, the signature of those functions require that the conversion is from that type to `Int` which I don't like - first because sizes are not `Int` naturally, and then because I might decide to have a custom data type anyway (say, `Inch`).

I could create a bunch of consts like:

```
    Small = 9.5             
    Medium = 11.5
    ...
```

But I'd also like to group them into a "proper" data type.

Any suggestions how to move forward?

Comment: I'd simply define a function `Size -> TheNumericTypeYouWant`. It looks like you do not really want to define a constant but a "constant which depends on the size" -- and that's a function, not a constant.

Comment: Something like this?
```
sizeToInch :: Size -> Inch
sizeToInch s |
    s == Small      = Inch  9.5 |
    ...
```
If that's acceptable, please turn your comment into an answer, so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a function, associating to each size-value a numeric value. E.g.

```
sizeToInch :: Size -> Double
sizeToInch Small  = 9.5
sizeToInch Medium = 11.5
...
```

If you want, you can also use a custom type to better represent the units:

```
newtype Inch = Inch { fromInch :: Double }

sizeToInch :: Size -> Inch
sizeToInch Small  = Inch 9.5
sizeToInch Medium = Inch 11.5
...
```

Note that the above `Inch` type won't let you directly sum `Inch` values using `+`, or perform any other arithmetic operation using the standard operators. You might want to add `deriving Num` to enable standard operators on that type. This will also allow multiplication, though, which is not ideal (an inch squared is not an inch). There are some libraries (like `dimensional`) that can rigorously handle units, but they can be overkill for such a simple task. Choose the design you are most comfortable with.